# Alinhamento do botão radio embaixo da imagem

Tags: radiobutton

Olá.

Tenho este código:

```
<div class="span12" style="padding: 1%; margin-left: 0">
    <div class="span3">
        <h2>Inicio da Palavra</h2>
        <img src= "/images/inicio.png"  width="300" height="202">
        <input type="radio" name="sentido" value="Início da Palavra"> 
    </div>

    <div class="span3">
        <h2>Final da Palavra</h2>
        <img src= "/images/final.png"  width="300" height="202">
        <input type="radio" name="sentido" value="Final da Palavra"> 
    </div>

    <div class="span3">
        <h2>Pé</h2>
        <img src= "/images/pe.png"  width="300" height="202">
        <input type="radio" name="sentido" value="Pé"> 
    </div>

    <div class="span3">
        <h2>Cabeça</h2>
        <img src= "/images/cabeca.png"  width="300" height="202">
        <input type="radio" name="sentido" value="Cabeça"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

O Botão do radio fica ao lado da imagem.

Como faço para deixar exatamente embaixo e centralizado ?

Obrigado

Comment: Centralizado em relação à imagem ou à div?

Comment: À imagem colega...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A imagem está dentro de uma `div` que ocupa a largura inteira da tela (ou do seu contêiner).

Se você centralizar o *radiobutton* sozinho, ele irá ficar no meio da `div` sem referência à imagem.

Como a imagem tem largura fixa, agrupe ela e o *radiobutton* numa `div` com a mesma largura da imagem (`300px`) e use `text-align: center` com o estilo abaixo:

> Alguns navegadores (como o Chrome, por exemplo) incluem uma pequena
>   margem padrão ao *radiobutton*. Por isso sugiro também incluir no CSS
>   o estilo abaixo para eliminar essa margem para que o elemento fique
>   melhor posicionado:
>
> ```
> input[type="radio"]{
>    margin: 0;
> }
> ```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.span3 div{
   width: 300px;
   text-align: center;
}

input[type="radio"]{
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="span12" style="padding: 1%; margin-left: 0">
   <div class="span3">
      <h2>Inicio da Palavra</h2>
      <div>
         <img src= "/images/inicio.png"  width="300" height="202">
         <input type="radio" name="sentido" value="Início da Palavra"> 
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Considerando que esta *div-filho* será a única dentro da classe `.span3`. Se pretender inserir outras `div`s, terá que colocar uma classe nela para não alterar as outras:

```css
.span3 .imagem{
   width: 300px;
   text-align: center;
}

input[type="radio"]{
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="span12" style="padding: 1%; margin-left: 0">
   <div class="span3">
      <h2>Inicio da Palavra</h2>
      <div class="imagem">
         <img src= "/images/inicio.png"  width="300" height="202">
         <input type="radio" name="sentido" value="Início da Palavra"> 
      </div>
      <div>
         Esta é outra div
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Só me tira uma dúvida, o que teria de ser feito caso o tamanho da imagem for relativo? (apenas curiosidade mesmo).

Comment: Daria na mesma. O text-align: center irá centralizar tudo dentro da div. Veja neste exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/n5z2dx89/... coloquei height="10" na imagem só pra visualizar melhor.

Answer (score 1):

É difícil te dar uma resposta que vai funcionar em todos os casos. Mas como a imagem tem um tamanho fixo de 300px, basta vc dar um `display:block` no input para ele passar para baixo da imagem, depois vc da um `margin-left` da metade da largura da imagem que seria 150px. E pra finalizar coloca um `transform:translateX` para fazer o `input` centralizar no próprio eixo.

**OBS:** Aqui deveria ser 50% `translateX(-48%)`, mas por algum motivo o Chorme estava renderizando errado, e com 48% parece que ficou bom...

```css
.span3 input {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 150px;
    transform: translateX(-48%); /* o ideal seria 50% aqui mas o Chrome cortou a borda do input com esse valor */
}
```

```html
    <div class="span12" style="padding: 1%; margin-left: 0">
        <div class="span3">
            <h2>Inicio da Palavra</h2>
            <img src= "/images/inicio.png"  width="300" height="202">
            <input type="radio" name="sentido" value="Início da Palavra"> 
        </div>

        <div class="span3">
            <h2>Final da Palavra</h2>
            <img src= "/images/final.png"  width="300" height="202">
            <input type="radio" name="sentido" value="Final da Palavra"> 
        </div>

        <div class="span3">
            <h2>Pé</h2>
            <img src= "/images/pe.png"  width="300" height="202">
            <input type="radio" name="sentido" value="Pé"> 
        </div>

        <div class="span3">
            <h2>Cabeça</h2>
            <img src= "/images/cabeca.png"  width="300" height="202">
            <input type="radio" name="sentido" value="Cabeça"> 
        </div>
    </div>
```